# How do you add edges to existing vertices in Gremlin-python?

Tags: python, gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlinpython

What is the standard way to add edges between two already existing vertices in gremlin-python? I've tried numerous iterations including the two code versions below, but unfortunately they all lead to errors.

Code snippet 1:

```
   v1= g.V().has("Customers", "OrderedId",1).next()
   v2 = g.V().has("Hotels", "Id", 1).next()
   e_id = v1.addE('HasVisited').to(v2).toList()
```

Error 1:

```
AttributeError: 'Vertex' object has no attribute 'addE'
```

Code Snippet 2

```
v1= g.V().has("Customers", "OrderedId",1).next()
v2 = g.V().has("Hotels", "Id", 1).next()
g.V(v2).as_('t').V(v1).addE("HasVisited").to("t").toList()
```

Error 2

```
KeyError: None
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably just do:

```
g.V().has("Customers", "OrderedId",1).as_('a').
  V().has("Hotels", "Id", 1).as_('b').
  addE("HasVisited").from_('a').to("b").iterate()
```

The first snippet you presented is simply an invalid API. You can't operate on a `Vertex` object directly and you should think of it as read-only. The second snippet, I'm less sure about. If `g.V(v2)` and `g.V(v1)` both independently return values, I would have expected that snippet to have created an edge.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion works!

I also tried the following snippet which I thought would work the same as your suggestion but got another KeyError. Could you provide any insights of why it would not work?

g.V(v1).as_('a').V(v2).as_('b').addE('HasVisited').from_('a').to('b').iterate()

Comment: what graph database are you using?

Comment: I am using OrientDB.

Comment: i'm not familiar with the OrientDB implementation these days, but maybe there is an issue with `Vertex` deserialization with OrientDB.